How to treat with a long title of a chapter in a book so that it can fit into one line in the header and not to break into 2 lines
I'm writing my thesis and I'm facing a trouble. The trouble is that the title of a certain chapter in my thesis is too long and it breaks into two lines in the header of the pages of the chapter (next to the page number) and this behavior is very bad to me. Is there any way to choose a smaller font size for the title of this chapter only? or to add dots? (also for the title of this chapter only). Also, I want to resize the number of the chapter that appears besides the title in the header. I really appreciate any help.
This is the code
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in, headsep=22pt, footskip=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase{\rightorleftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\hspace{0.1cm} #1}{}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\S\thesection.\hspace{0.25cm}#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rightorleftmark}{%
\begingroup\protected@edef\x{\rightmark}%
 \ifx\x\@empty
  \endgroup\leftmark
 \else
   \endgroup\rightmark
 \fi}
\makeatother
%==============================================================
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter With Small Title}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{A Long Title of Chapter That Does not Fit Into One Line So That It Has To Be 
  Broken Into Two Lines}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}


\chapter[short version]{a long title ...}

I want the short version to be the lone version but with a font size scriptsize. Also I need the chapter number preceding the title to in the font size scriptsize. Is it possible? @DavidCarlisle
Also, unfortunately, the short version appears in toc instead of the lone version.

Let's add that it would be ugly for a single chapter to have different font size in the header! Also, automatically (arbitrarily) cutting off the text with dots would also not be very nice. Hence the appropriate solution is to define a short title yourself, as shown by @DavidCarlisle.
If you want to (uniformly) change the font or general formatting of headings, you can change the definitions of the \fancyhead that you already use: probably changing \small to \scriptsize will give you what you want.

have you seen any book that does that?, it would look rather odd. you could use [\tiny a horribly squashed long version]{a long title} but please don't

Why do you insist on reproducing the full long chapter title in the header line?

@HusseinEid several classes and packages make it possible to specify the chapter title, the page head and the toc entry separately

Well. Your suggestions are all good. But isn't it odd to have a title in the header that is different from the original title in the chapter? Is it usual in books?!

No, it isn't odd. Yes, it is usual in books. If possible, a shorter title is probably preferable, but, where that's not desirable or practical, the usual practice is to use a shortened version in the header. It would, however, be very odd to arbitrarily truncate the title or to format it differently from the headers of other chapters.
